# wx.TaskBarIcon in Ubuntu 13.04 (GNOME or Unity)

Tags: python, wxpython, systray, appindicator

I've used `wx.TaskBarIcon` to successfully implement a systray interface to my application on Windows and Mac but am having severe trouble with it on Ubuntu.

There's already been two SO questions regarding this on previous versions of Ubuntu:

- [wxTaskBarIcon in Ubuntu 12.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521006/wxtaskbaricon-in-ubuntu-12-10)
- [wx.TaskBarIcon on Ubuntu 11.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144756/wx-taskbaricon-on-ubuntu-11-04)

Neither provide real answers or workarounds.

As I understand it, the systray whitelist was implemented [and was subsequently obsoleted](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/unity-notification-area-systray.html), which apparently leaves wxWidgets and wxPython applications completely unable to display a system tray.

The Ubuntu forums hint at the fact that I need to code up an 'AppIndicator'. How can this possibly work with wxPython?

**Update**

It was clear that wxWidgets was never going to work with Unity.

I tried GNOME. Below are the results:

[image: a screenie of the supposed taskbar]

The presentation is just awful: the icon was floating in the middle of nowhere. However, when it is clicked, the context menu does come up as it should.

Comment: Which version of wxPython? Did you see this: http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/15644

Comment: I'm using 2.9.5.0. I made that ticket!!!

Comment: Upstream ticket created by OP, no further action needed here on SO