# Does TideSDK's Ti.UI.addTray work in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, sdk, tidesdk

I was testing out a TideSDK example using the following code from github.

https://github.com/meeech/Menu-App

I am using Ubuntu and what I would expect to happen is a new tray icon appearing in the right hand side of the tray along the menu. It simply does not appear.

Would this most likely be a problem with the SDK or an issue with Ubuntu's tray config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Ubuntu's Unity broke several cross platform UI toolkits that rely on the freedesktop.org specification of the [System Tray Protocol](http://freedesktop.org/Standards/systemtray-spec) including [wxWidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144756/wx-taskbaricon-on-ubuntu-11-04) (and [wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793890/wx-taskbaricon-in-ubuntu-13-04-gnome-or-unity)), [QT](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5916) (since patched) and [TideSDK](https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues/175).  Unity uses its own [Application Indicator](https://unity.ubuntu.com/projects/appindicators/) api now.

More specifically, [TideSDK](https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/blob/develop/src/modules/ui/gtk/gtk_tray_item.cpp) uses the [GtkStatusIcon](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStatusIcon.html) which isn't honored by Unity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer.